# error on install Community Server/ Document server onlyoffice

Tags: 18.04, lxc, mono, nextcloud, elasticsearch

when try to install only office server based on there [Installing Community Server for Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/community/linux-installation.aspx)
so step by step until the latest command

```
sudo apt-get install onlyoffice-communityserver
```

> get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: onlyoffice-communityserver :
Depends: mono-webserver-hyperfastcgi but it is not going to be installed
Depends: elasticsearch (= 6.5.0) but 7.2.0 is to be installed
```

and when try to install elasticsearch 6.5.0 get an error

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/install-of-apt-package-is-failing/150385/2

so what to do?

Comment: you know the goal to install onlyoffice-communityserver require specific version not the latest one as mentions, and i was following guide (official) an old one, or need to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after taking a while the solution was:
for **elasticsearch error**  look like was need to install java repo by

```
apt-get install -yq openjdk-11-jdk
```

**if not found try**

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa && apt update
```

**get an error try to**

```
apt-get install -yq openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

**how to download elasticsearch deb?**
     
just change the exenstion of url from rpm to deb will be

https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.5.0.deb

about **mono-webserver-hyperfastcgi** by adding repo link to sources

```
  echo "deb https://d2nlctn12v279m.cloudfront.net/repo/mono/ubuntu bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-extra.list
```

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys CB2DE8E5
```

```
apt update
```

```
apt install mono-webserver-hyperfastcgi
```

**get an error try to**

```
apt install mono-webserver-hyperfastcgi="0.4-7"
```

or

```
apt install mono-webserver-hyperfastcgi="0.4-4"
```

**still getting an errors ?**

> check this [file](https://download.onlyoffice.com/install/install-Debian/install-preq.sh)  or try to install it using script [Installing
>   Community Edition from RPM/DEB packages using the provided script](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/opensource/opensource-script-rpm-deb-installation.aspx)

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

For Installation issues about "Elastic-Search 6.5.0" this is one possible Solution (Install manually Elastic-Search 6.5.0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

- Elasticsearch 6.5.0 Source: https://www.elastic.co/de/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-6-5-0
- Depencies JAVA JDK 8:
  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31845

***Additional:***

***The following Solution only works for Upgrading/Updating existing Communityserver Installations:***

You have to mark the Elastic-Search Package on Hold in terminal-Console on your Server: "sudo apt-mark hold elasticsearch"

Source-Link: [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

After this you can "Upgrade/Update" your Onlyoffice-CommunityServer.

Good Luck.

Sincerly, Karmakaze

Answer (score 0):

If you’re a user of Ubuntu 20.04 or Ubuntu official flavors, you can easily install **ONLYOFFICE** Desktop Editors from snap package. To install **ONLYOFFICE** Desktop Editors on Ubuntu 20.04 via snap, simply run the following command:

```
snap install onlyoffice-desktopeditors
snap run onlyoffice-desktopeditors
```